# How to compile statically linked go program (1.3)?

Tags: linux, go, debian, static-linking

I'm trying to compile a small go program statically (for the purpose of playing with Rocket). I'm running on Debian Jessie (Mint version). I installed the `golang-go` package. The Rocket documentation gives examples of how to compile statically for go version 1.4 and 1.5

```
1.4
$ CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o hello -a -installsuffix cgo .

1.5:
$ CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o hello -a -tags netgo -ldflags '-w' .
```

Unfortunately, `go version` says I'm running 1.3.

```
$ go version
go version go1.3.3 linux/amd64
```

I tried the 1.4 version, hoping it would for for 1.3, but no such luck. I'm not sure if I installed all the debian packages I even needed?

I *was* able to compile the file and run it using just `go build howdy.go`. The small app works as expected, but `ldd` shows it has multiple dynamic dependencies:

```
$ ldd howdy
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe72d7e000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3b22e5a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3b22ab1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3b23077000)
```

For complete disclosure, the small program I'm trying to compile statically (`howdy.go`) is:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Printf("request from %v\n", r.RemoteAddr)
        w.Write([]byte("howdy\n"))
    })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil))
}
```

Additionally, output of go -x is:

```
$ go build -x howdy.go
WORK=/tmp/go-build496765737
mkdir -p $WORK/command-line-arguments/_obj/
cd /home/travisg/rkt-v0.10.0
/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6g -o $WORK/command-line-arguments.a -trimpath $WORK -p command-line-arguments -complete -D _/home/travisg/rkt-v0.10.0 -I $WORK -pack ./howdy.go
cd .
/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6l -o howdy -L $WORK -extld=gcc $WORK/command-line-arguments.a
```

and output of go env is:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Comment: You could always use the Go Version Manager https://github.com/moovweb/gvm to install Go 1.4 or 1.5 and use that perhaps.

Comment: The method from go1.4 worked for me on 1.3. Can you put the output of `go env`? Also, you can check how things are being built with the `-x` option. (however, I would really recommend instilling a current version of Go)

Comment: Added those. I was really just trying to explore `Rocket`, was hoping to not have to learn `Go` in great deal as a side tangent. Wish the `Rocket` guys weren't so bleeding edge I guess.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call using the supported version of go "bleeding edge". Try installing the official release of go from golang.org

Comment: We are all getting off topic here. Go should be able to compile in this environment without dependencies. Perhaps we should look at the problem as stated first.

Comment: I upgraded to debian stretch. It has version 1.5

Answer (score 1):

this is what worked for me:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 \
go build -a -installsuffix cgo -ldflags '-s' -o server server.go
```

from:

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9344